# Is Convention Over Configuration "Knowledge in the World" or "Knowledge In Your Head"?

Tags: design-patterns, coding-standards, inversion-of-control

In Don Norman's seminal work "[The Design of Everyday Things](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E257T6C)", the author coined the phrases and explains the difference between "Knowledge in the World" and "Knowledge In Your Head"; an example of this is a multi-switch light panel that can either incorporate "Knowledge in the World"  by being a model/map of the room, with the switches in the corresponding location, or "Knowledge In Your Head" (which is how they are almost always designed/implemented) when you have to memorize which switch toggles which light.

You could think of "Knowledge in the World" as something you can deduce by using observation and logic, and "Knowledge in your Head" as something that has to be memorized.

In the world of DI, and "Auto-Registration," which relies on the "Convention Over Configuration" pattern, would using this process be a case of the programmer using "Knowledge in the World" (the functionality is expected, as the framework provides it) or is it "Knowledge In Your Head" (the programmer has to be aware of and learn the convention).

I am taking the wishy-washy/middle-of-the-road view that Convention Over Configuration is a midway world twixt the two.

Am I wrong?

Comment: By convention, knowledge in your head is knowledge in the world, by configuration, knowledge in the world is knowledge in your head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convention Over Configuration is pretty much by definition "Knowledge in the World" - the convention is always meant to be so "obvious" that you don't have to learn much: things like having URLs automatically mapped to controller classes and DB tables to model classes. The same for auto-registration DI - you have objects automatically instantiated and injected into others based on naming conventions. It "just works".

Of course, the problem is that in practice it's not always (and almost never in sufficiently large systems) that simple. You have special requirements and edge cases not covered by the conventions, and it stops working. The problem then is that all this "magic" you're supposed to depend on is opaque to you and relies on mechanisms that are quite complex by themselves. And you have to invest a lot of time to learn how it works so you can make it work the way you need and fix it when it breaks. And then it has become "Knowledge in your head".

But in a well-designed and correctly-used system, this should be rare enough that it's still worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks for convincing me to close vote, I was on the edge but you make a very strong and good argument for your opinion which I couldn't disagree with more, I could post an answer that totally disagrees with you and backs up my point and my opinion with a logical explanation, which would be a fine thing to do. The problem with this question is neither "yes" or "no" can be anything but wishy-washy opinion so I'm voting to close as opinion based. I won't -1 even though I think you're wrong just because...it's your opinion, and rightness or wrongness doesn't play into that

Comment: @JimmyHoffa - I'm curious to hear your thoughts on it.

Comment: @MikePartridge In my book if it's not written down it's in your head, convention is by definition things that work implicitly->not written down. Configuration is the explicit "Here's how it shall and does work all written right here for everyone to see" I would say that's in the world because anybody can look at it, they don't have to already have the convention in their head. When people who don't know the convention see things by convention they just see pure magic because the trappings aren't in their head yet; they have to check a manual, just like if they saw a crazy universal switchpanel

Comment: Even a "well-designed system" often relies on a graph of third-party dependencies n-levels deep.  It almost always inevitably happens that defects in any of your direct or transitive dependencies incurs a compounding complexity cost to dependent components and, inevitably, your own code base.  This is furthermore compounded when defects or unexpected behaviour relates to conventions, which, as stated, is difficult to deal with due to its opaqueness.  Thus, simply put, coding by convention leads to leaky abstractions.  It compounds issues the more you depend on it, and erodes code over time.

Answer (score 1):

Although Convention over Configuration is *supposed* to be 'Knowledge in the World' it invariably isnt.

```
public class MyController(IMyService service)...

public class DefaultService : IMyService...

public class ASpecialService: IMyService...
```

Which service is used?

Answer (score 0):

How do you acquire that knowledge?

"Knowledge in the world": mostly by experience and conventions. In your switch example, you know already what a plan is and how to map it to the actual room.

"Knowledge in your head": mostly by experimentation - in the switch example, you try them.

From that perspective, convention over configuration is definitely "knowledge in the world".

(Note that while most house switches end up 'knowledge in your head', they still respect some 'knowledge in the world' conventions such as being - generally - in the same room as the lights and - if your electrician is any good - roughly ordered like the lights in a multi switch configuration)